# Is there a way to get predictable actor naming with Akka-Stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm using an `ActorPublisher` as an Akka-Stream `Source`. I can't figure out how to predictably name the input actor so I can send it messages from other parts of my application. I'm instantiating my source like so:

```
val src = Source[Task](Props(classOf[TaskListener], this), "task-listener")
```

I get an `ActorRef` when I materialize the stream, but the path for it is dynamically generated, and it only uses my provided name as part of a code-generated flow-centric naming scheme.

Is there any way to have this front-end actor source have an explicit name or am I stuck passing the ActorRef around?

If I can't explicitly name it does this mean you can't use Akka-Stream directly with remoting?

**EDIT:** I can find my actor using relative pathing now, but I still need to figure out how to name my `Flow` so I can understand what the full path to the actor in question will be.

**EDIT:** (akka version info below, scala 2.11.6)

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.9"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-experimental" % "1.0-M4"
```

**EDIT:** The friendly folks over at the akka-user google group have enlightened me, and suggest that the proper way to deal with this is by passing around the `ActorRef` that results from the `runWith()` call itself and not using `.actorSelection()`. I will update this question if I find that this state of affairs changes in the future. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I understand that over 3 years passed, but could you please share the way you dealed with this finally, because I struggle with the exact same task

Comment: @YoZH I created a `Source` using `Source.actorPublisher`, then created a `Flow` on which i called `flow.runWith(src)` -- but that method has been deprecated since.  Hopefully you have navigated your way around the problem by now.

Answer (score 2):

Good way to solve this, will be adding Group router with specific path, then you can tell router where it can find you actors (routees).

By doing this you will decouple your concrete actor group and maintain single point of entry to your Source pool via router. Also you will be able to make this router cluster aware in future.

You can also look into ActorFlowMaterializer - http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/index.html#akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer itself. You can find this comment in source code:

```
/** The `namePrefix` is used as the first part of the names of the actors running
  * the processing steps. The default `namePrefix` is `"flow"`. The actor names are built up of
  * `namePrefix-flowNumber-flowStepNumber-stepName`.
  */
def create(settings: ActorFlowMaterializerSettings, context: ActorRefFactory, namePrefix: String): ActorFlowMaterializer =
apply(Option(settings), Option(namePrefix))(context)
```

Comment: This is a good way to abstract the actors, but what I need is to be able to resolve the actors from a path. For that purpose your solution is no different than sharing the ActorRef. But good thinking regardless.

Comment: Another solution can be sending Identify message to actors under your ActorSelection, and listen to ActorIdentity reply which will contain ActorRef. You also can create custom message if you wish. As far as i remember Flow will have your name as are prefix, like task-listener*.

Comment: Also about naming, if you use ActorFlowMaterializer, you can see how actors are named, and you control prefix of this actors by providing your custom prefix to Materializer itself. Look here for more info - http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/index.html#akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer.

Comment: The actor names are built up of
   * `namePrefix-flowNumber-flowStepNumber-stepName`.

Comment: I've gone down the Materializer route, the result being that it doesn't affect the top level supervision name, but only the prefix on the dynamically created actors. YoK, in your example there would still be a $a or something similar above that actor that is dynamically named.

Comment: @YoK could you please help me understand whats namePrefix-flowNumber-flowStepNumber-stepName is with some example?